# Is half space on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Quick question, given $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the half space $H = \{(x,y): y \leq 0\}$ a manifold?

I approached this directly using the definition: A topological manifold is a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold)

I think we are good on both the locally Euclidean and Hausdorff part. Can someone verify whether if this is indeed a manifold (or not)?

Comment: It is a "manifold with boundary." The points $(x,0)$ do not have neighborhoods that are homeomorphic to an open disk.

Comment: It's a manifold with boundary ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary ).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So if we removed the boundary then the open half space would be a manifold?

Comment: Any open subset of $\textbf{R}^n$ is trivially a manifold using the identity homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, the open half-plane $H^+$ is a manifold - it is, in fact, homeomorphic to the entire plane, via $\mathbb R^2\to H^{+}$ defined by $(x,y)\to (x,e^y)$.

Comment: @danielson Right...I was just confused because someone suddenly came up to me and said half space is not a manifold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a manifold with boundary, which is defined on the same Wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: Senator what is the difference between a manifold with boundary versus just a manifold? Are you saying that it is not a manifold but "a manifold with a boundary"?

Comment: I'm not a senator, but yes. Read the definitions and the comments on your question: In a manifold, every point must have a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. In $H$, the points with $y=0$ do not have such a neighborhood.

Comment: I think the OP is commenting on a grammatical problem. Usually in English an "X with Y" must be an X before  you can even ask whether it has a Y. A ring with identity must be a ring before you can see whether it has an identity. In this case a manifold with boundary is (somewhat confusingly) not a manifold.

Comment: Never thought about this. You're right, it is a bit confusing.